# Should I use Public setter for events/messages in Axon?

Tags: domain-driven-design, axon

Can we have public setters for the member variables in events/messages created and used through in Axon Framework?

As per my knowledge, events are something that *have happened in the past*, making them conceptually immutable. Hence, we should not have public setter.

Can someone please confirm this for me?

Answer (score 1):

As you stated correctly, `Events` are "things from the past" which means they already happened and you should keep them and their contents **immutable**.

Since they are Java classes, you *can* create `setters` but on an Event Sourcing perspective you *shouldn't*.